# Can't get entity models working in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entities

I seem to cannot be able to get entities to work in MVC3, I cannot access them in my controller anywhere. I created UserDataModel.edmx from my Users table and generated a context file UserDataModel.tt with UserDataModel.cs, but I cannot reference that at all in my controller. Am I missing something? I have followed this tutorial to no success:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489

Thanks

Comment: Post code please so folks here can better assist you. Also post any releveant error message and possibly your connection string too.

Comment: Do you declared UserDataModelEntities _context = new UserDataModelEntities() ?

Answer (score 0):

Expand (after compile) UserDataModel.tt, in there you will see your generated classes. Look in there and open up a class. You should see the namespace the class is in. 
Reference that entire namespace in your controller (ie if its MyProject.MyEntities.Customer.cs have a

```
using MyProject.MyEntities;
..
..

public ActionResult Index()
{
  using(var context = new YourContextClassName())
 {
    return View( context.Customers.ToList());
 }
}
```

As a basic basic example.